# is it Possible to pass parameter in UIView Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I ve got a view controller . when i pass an extra object  I m getting this error @No visible interface in the below function .could u help me out.below is the code.where i am passing an object of type photo ..

```
  ItemImageView *itemImage = [[ItemImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentPhotoPositionX,0,pageButtonWidth,pageButtonHeight) andPhoto:photo];

@ItemImageview


 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame :andPhoto:(Photo *)photo
   {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code

    //Create Activity Indicator
     activityIndicator= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225, 115, 30, 30)];
    [activityIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [self addSubview:activityIndicator];

    //Create Label Comments

    lblComments = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30.0f, 100.0f, 60.0f, 43.0f)];
    [lblComments setText:@"Comments"];
    [lblComments setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self addSubview:lblComments];

    //Create Label Likes

    lblLikes = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 60.0f, 43.0f)];
    [lblLikes setText:@"Likes"];
    [lblLikes setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self addSubview:lblLikes];


    //Create Item Button

    btnItem = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btnItem addTarget:self
                action:@selector(:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnItem.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 144.0f, 143.0f);
    [self addSubview:btnItem];


}

return self;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change it into:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andPhoto:(Photo *)photo
```

And also remember to add it to your .h file.

Comment: I m not able to do that .i changed my function definition to the one you have given and when i call my function its showing error...i ll update my answer

Comment: ':andPhoto:' remove the first ':'